# JSX component doesn't render map of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i'm trying to make a list when users selects their fav links onClick ...

Any idea why this doesn't work? it will push values to state.array in console.log but JSX will not render in ul.li

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      link: {
        name: "",
        type: "",
        size: "",
        tests: []
      },
      tests: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  onClick = e => {
    const linktests = this.state.link.tests;
    console.log("clicked");

    linktests.push(e.target.innerText);
    console.log("link tests : " + linktests);
  };
  render() {
    const { link, tests } = this.state;
    const linktests = this.state.link.tests;
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="link">
          {linktests.map(stuff => (
            <ul>
              <li> {stuff} </li>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </div>
        <br></br>
        {tests.map(stuff => (
          <ul>
            <li onClick={this.onClick} value={stuff}>
              {stuff}
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

hope someone can help :D <3 thanks

Comment: Always use `this.setState` to update your state ! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Comment: @Kornflexx , i'm newbie and my array set states doesn't works : ( if u know tell me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the new links to the state. Also use `concat` or `slice` on the original state array to avoid mutating it directly.

```
 onClick = e => {
    const linktests = this.state.link.tests.concat();
    console.log("clicked");

    linktests.push(e.target.innerText);
    this.setState({link: { ...this.state.link, tests: linktests});
  };
```

Comment: rendering works , thanks. but it doesn't update the state in console log, why is that?

Comment: @tafhim `setState` is async, so you won't see the changes in console immediately. For that you'll need to pass a callback to `setState`: `this.setState({link: { ...this.state.link, tests: linktests}, () => console.log(this.state.link))`.